# Использование seleniumwire.webdriver.Remote с прокси в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

При использование появилась нужда использовать **socks5 auth** прокси, обычно я делал это так

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

options = {
        'proxy': {
            'http': "socks5h://" + proxy,
            'https': "socks5h://" + proxy,
            'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1' # ,dev_server:8080
            }
        }
webdriver.Firefox(
        seleniumwire_options=options
)
```

А как это сделать в этом случае ?

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

selenium_url = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"
caps = {'browserName': 'chrome'}
driver = webdriver.Remote(
           command_executor=selenium_url, 
           desired_capabilities=caps
         )
```